# Difference output after a query

Tags: php, mysql

I've the following query:

```
SELECT BIL_Date,
SUM(BIL_Rate * BIL_Quantity) AS sumRevAccomodation,
COUNT(*) AS total_nights
FROM `___BillableDatas`
WHERE BIL_HotelId = 'AAA00'
AND BIL_Date BETWEEN "2017-04-10" AND "2017-04-18"
AND BIL_Type = "Night"
AND BIL_Status != "Cancelled"
GROUP BY BIL_Date ASC
```

...which gives me this result...

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------+
| BIL_Date   | sumRevAccomodation | total_nights |
+------------+--------------------+--------------+
| 2017-04-10 |             285.00 |            3 |
| 2017-04-11 |             285.00 |            3 |
| 2017-04-12 |             305.00 |            3 |
| 2017-04-13 |             310.00 |            3 |
| 2017-04-14 |             205.00 |            2 |
| 2017-04-15 |             180.00 |            2 |
| 2017-04-16 |             180.00 |            2 |
| 2017-04-17 |             190.00 |            2 |
| 2017-04-18 |             190.00 |            2 |
+------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

But after this code, the first value is miss:

```
$fetch = $query->fetch();
$count = $query->rowCount();

if($count >= 1) {
    while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $bills[] = [
            'BIL_Date' => $fetch['BIL_Date'],
            'BIL_Revenues' => $fetch['sumRevAccomodation'],
            'BIL_NightNb' => $fetch['total_nights']
        ];
    }
}
```

What's the problem ?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7594a8/1

Thanks.

Comment: That's all the code?

Comment: Right after the second part, `$bills` do not contain the info for the `2017-04-10`.

Comment: `//$fetch = $query->fetch();` comment this line and try

Comment: @Bhaskar: that was the problem... Thanks. A copy/paste problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching first value in your first line, and never using it, so you are loosing it.

```
$fetch = $query->fetch(); // <---- HERE
$count = $query->rowCount();

if($count >= 1)
```